# UILabel autolayout bottom right constraints not working

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

```
let lbl = UILabel()
lbl.textColor = UIColor.RGB(0x74, g: 0x75, b: 0x75)
lbl.text = "180/180"
lbl.sizeToFit()
self.addSubview(lbl)
self.charsLimitLbl = lbl
lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

let rightConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[item]-padding-|", 
                                                 options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), 
                                                 metrics: ["padding" : padding], 
                                                 views: ["item" : lbl])
self.addConstraints(rightVonstraints)
let bottomConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[item]-padding-|", 
                                                       options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
                                                       metrics: ["padding" : padding], 
                                                       views: ["item" : lbl])

self.addConstraints(bottomConstraints)
lbl.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriorityRequired, for: .horizontal)
```

I'm adding this label as a subview of UITextView and for some reason my label gets negative origin:

> App.WPPUILabel: 0x7f9132209830; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (**-39.5 
>   -14.5;** 39.5 14.5); text = '54/180'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = _UILabelLayer: 0x63800009ddd0

Im'm calling these functions everywhere I can without any effect:

```
self.layoutIfNeeded()
self.layoutSubviews()
self.setNeedsLayout()
```

Comment: just a guess, you didn't set the padding on the other side? H:|-missingPadding-[item]-padding-|

Comment: No, because "-|" is only at one - right side

Comment: yes you have a constraints on the right side but does not have a proper or full constraints, its the same as the bottom. if you want your label to be flushed it should be H:|[item]-padding@750-| or something like that

Comment: I do not want full constrains, I want label to have its intrinsic content size. Changing to  H:|-missingPadding-[item]-padding-| would stretch the label to superview's width minus paddings